# "In" or "reverse contains" query in Django filters for comparing strings

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I'm writing the backend code for an autocomplete form. Each entry I return is described by a category name and a number within that category.

When the user types "CAT123", I want to use Django filters to filter down to category names or numbers that are contained in the user's query.

In other words, I want to execute a query like:

```
Entry.objects.filter(Q(category__in = query) | Q(num__in = query))
```

where **the filters test if category `AAA` is in query `AAA 555`, and if number `555` is in query `AAA 555`**, respectively.

However, `__in` seems to only work for lists, and `__contains` checks the other way ('AAA 555' is not in 'AAA').

**What's the right filter expression to use for this "is contained in a string" idea?**

Or is there a way to reverse the `contains` expression, so that the filter looks like `Q(query__contains = category)`?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `__contains` but you should split the query into category and number parts *before* you use it. This is a good case for using regex. Below is a simple example, but be aware that this won't work well for unicode category names (for example, with letters such as üéøā). Look around for more tutorials if you want a more flexible regex.

```
import re

entries = [
        "sdf",
        "A124",
        "124",
        "ASDF 124",
        ]

for i, e in enumerate(entries):
    number = re.search(r'\d+', e)
    word = re.search(r'[A-Za-z]+', e)
    print i
    if number:
        print( "    " + number.group() )
    if word:
        print( "    " + word.group() )
```

returns:

```
0
    sdf
1
    124
    A
2
    124
3
    124
    ASDF
```

You would use the captured matches like this:

```
Entry.objects.filter(Q(category__contains = word) | Q(num__contains = number))
```